# Visual Studio 2022 git error Unable to negotiate with {0} port {1}: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

After updating VS 2022 to 17.1.1, I have a problem with Git. I can't comment, for example, fetch or pusl. I get a message

> Fetching from origin
> Unable to negotiate with {0} port {1}: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa
> Failed to fetch from the remote repository. See the Output window for more details.
> Error encountered while fetching: Failed to fetch from the remote repository. See the Output window for more details.

However, on VS 2019 it works fine, and in SourceTree I can make any comments. So it's not a problem with buggy ssh-rsa.

How can I solve it?

Comment: The `{0}` and `{1}` indicate that someone messed up some error message software, but the base problem is likely that the modern software refuses to use the obsolete (no longer secure) `ssh-rsa` encryption. Your older VS and your SourceTree software are still willing to use the insecure encryption. If you upgrade the *server* to offer a more-secure encryption, the problem should go away. (There *may* also be some setting you can set in your VS2022 client to allow insecure connections.)

Comment: This answer will help you ongoing towards https://stackoverflow.com/a/72804021/6064025

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This also happened to me today when I upgraded to the latest version in VS 2019 Community Edition (but the IP address and port of the previously configured Git connection appeared for me).

Visual Studio IDE has an own Git extension. Try to search for that instance in the folder hierarchy and under it the ssh configuration file
VS2019 Community Edition:

`%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\MicrosoftVisualStudio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\etc\ssh\ssh_config`

Add this configuration to the end of this file with the appropriate git server hostname or IP address
or both separated by space (to enable the deprecated/insecure encryption at client side):

```
Host gitserver.local
  HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
  PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

This was the solution for me.

There may be another solution to upgrade the Git server-side to support more secure encryptions (e.g. rsa-sha2-256 or 512).

Comment: It worked, when I entered the correct data into the file, it worked. Thanks

Comment: It worked for me, but this was not what I expected. Why doesn't Visual Studio adhere to ~/.ssh/config?

Answer (score 1):

A bit old, but for completeness.

If you update VS 2022 you have to add the lines to the ssh_config file again.

To prevent that, just use another keytype:

- generate new key via: `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email"`
- take the content of id_ed25519.pub and add to you git account profile (we use bitbucket)
- you may have to add the id_ed25519 and id_ed25519.pub to the .ssh folder

everything works like a charm